# Bootstrap page Overflow-x hidden, one element on page on IOS still scrolls left and right

Tags: html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want my cordova app to look less like a web app and more like a real app by eliminating left and right scroll.

I've set the overflow-x property to hidden on the html and body tags, and that works for all but the page below, which scrolls left and right but shouldn't.

Have I misconstructed the grid? I've tried to apply the "overlow-x: hidden" property to an enclosing div instead of the body and html as suggested elsewhere, tried applying the property to the individual divs, attempted limiting width on the divs. I've tried changing the html position to fixed (which fixes the left-right scroll but also stops up down which I need). You [can view the page below on an iOS device to see the behaviour here](http://www.brian-fitzgerald.net/i-ching/i/doodle.html). Which of my lousy skillsets -- css, html, or bootstrap -- is letting me down here?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="position: relative; min-height: 100%;">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
        <title>
            My Awesome Title
        </title>
        <meta name="generator" content="BBEdit 11.0" /> 

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/entypo.min.css"> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/bootbox.min.js">
        </script>
        <style>
            html, body {
            overflow-x: hidden !important;
            }
        </style>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' /> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" style="background-color:#F8F8F8;">
                    <h2 class="text-center">
                        My Awesome Title
                    </h2>
                    <br /> 
                    <div id="hexpix" class="center-block">
                        <br /><br /> 
                        <div id="hexpixdiv">
                        </div>
                    </div>
<!-- Alert Space -->
                    <div id="AlertSpace" class="center-block" style="text-align:center; width:75%">
                    </div>
                    <br /> 
<!-- Hex Content Space for text  -->
                    <div id="hexindex" class="text-center">
                    </div>
<!-- hexindex close -->
                    <div id="hexcontent" class="text-center">
                    <!-- 
    <p>
                            Blah blah this text should NOT scroll left and right because overflow-x is set to hidden but it slides back and forth like a hotplate on butter. Why, people, Why?
                            <p>
 -->

                    </div>
<!-- hexcontent close -->
                    <div id='HelpButton'>
                    </div>
                </div>
<!-- Column class close-->
            </div>
<!-- Row class close-->
            <br /> 
        </div>
<!--Container close-->
        <div id="sharestrip" style="position: absolute; bottom:40px; width:100%; height:10px;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="Reddit">
                        <span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="SMS">
                        <span class="icon-export">
                        </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="Email">
                        <span class="icon-gmail">
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="Twitter">
                        <span class="icon-twitter">
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="Facebook">
                        <span class="icon-facebook">
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tumblr">
                        <span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
<!-- Row -->
        </div>
<!-- Sharestrip -->
        <div id="footer" style="position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;  height: 20px;">
<!-- See hex.css for custom css on this -->
            <div class="col-xs-12 navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                                <span class="nav-link">
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" 
                            <span class="nav-link">
                                1
                            </span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                                <span class="nav-link">
                                    2
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-2 text-center">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                                <span class="nav-link">
                                    3
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                                <span class="nav-link">
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
<!-- End Row -->
                </div>
<!-- End Container -->
            </div>
<!-- End Navbar -->
        </div>
<!-- End Footer -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you  set overflow: hidden to element it doesn't mean it stops to be scrollable... it just hides the scrollbar. Since mobile devices scroll contents when touching anywhere on the element, it just remains scrollable.

The fact is - your website is scrollable on X-Axis even on desktop devices, you just hide it by using `overflow-x: hidden` on body tag.

The reason why your website is x-scrollable on all devices is that you forgot to add **`class="container"`** to **`<div id="sharestrip"...`** and the row inside it has `100%+15px(left margin)+15px(right margin)` which is bigger than window width.

This behaviour is reduced by `.container` by it's `padding-left: 15px and padding-right: 15px`, so simply you need to remember of adding class="container" to parent of the row.

Comment: I put all rows in .container divs but it didn't change the behaviour: [Revised html here](http://www.brian-fitzgerald.net/i-ching/i/doodle2.html).

Comment: Yes, you fixed the `sharestrip`, but also edited footer too and now footer is breaking the website, placing `.container` directly in next `.container` is not a good idea though.

Comment: Whoops. Sorry. Yes, you're right I didn't mean to nest .container tags. I put a [CodePen together here with the layout I intended](https://codepen.io/brianfit/pen/MyGEXy/), the container still [slides left and right on an ios device](https://s.codepen.io/brianfit/debug/MyGEXy) though the .navbar-fixed element, interestingly, does not: it stays rock solid across the width of the page.

Comment: Now on desktop layout works fine even when resizing the window, I think i'd need an iphone to check what's going to there, so for now sorry to say, but can't investigate the issue.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a go and sharing those bits about x-scrollable pages and padding -- digging in to the navbar css now to see if that contains a clue on how it anchors hard to the width. The coloring in the pen suggests it's the body that's overflowing and not adjusting to the viewport width for some reason.